# SQL*Loader error only when calling via Python subprocess

Tags: python, oracle, shell, sql-loader

I have a python script that receives a large csv file and should load the data into an Oracle table. The plan is to use SQL Loader to accomplish this.

I have Instant Client 19.8 installed with SQL Loader. My Python code is run via this script

```
#!/bin/sh

PY=py

APP_HOME=/C/Users/.../Projects/.../updates
APP_BIN=$APP_HOME/bin
APP_LIB=$APP_HOME/lib
APP_CONFIG=$APP_HOME/config
APP_LOGS=$APP_HOME/logs
APP_DATA=$APP_HOME/data
APP_OUTPUT=$APP_HOME/output

GLOBAL_ENV_DIR=$APP_HOME/ENV

export APP_HOME
export APP_BIN
export APP_LIB
export APP_CONFIG
export APP_LOGS
export APP_DATA
export APP_OUTPUT
export GLOBAL_ENV_DIR

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/C/Oracle/instantclient_19_8
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$APP_HOME:$APP_BIN:$APP_LIB:$APP_LIB/util:$APP_CONFIG:$APP_LOGS:$APP_DATA:$APP_OUTPUT:

echo $PYTHONPATH

echo
echo $PY $APP_BIN/update/update_processor.py --globalenvdir $GLOBAL_ENV_DIR --apphomedir $APP_HOME  --date 01012020 $1 $2 $3 $4
echo

$PY $APP_BIN/update/update_processor.py --globalenvdir $GLOBAL_ENV_DIR --apphomedir $APP_HOME  --date 01012020 $1 $2 $3 $4
```

Then, I attempt to run SQL Loader like this

```
subprocess.call('sqlldr user/pass@.../... control=config/update_processor.ctl data=data/data.dat')
```

And see this error

```
Message 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=ULMessage 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UL
```

I can of course run SQL Loader on its own or from a separate Python script, so I assume something is not configured correctly in my shell script?

Comment: I just spent some time cobbling together something similar and did not see that error.  If you can update your question with a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then I can look again.  Otherwise, check that the environment variables are being propagated.  You may find it safer to use ldconfig instead of setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH (see the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst)).

Comment: I quite literally just created an empty /instantclient/rdbms/mesg folder which I deleted after one run and it started working correctly... Not sure why it would have needed that since I was under the impression that folder was only needed with full installs of an Oracle client.

Answer (score 1):

You should have set `ORACLE_HOME` env variable. For example you can set it in command line:

```
subprocess.call('ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle-home sqlldr user/pass@.../... control=config/update_processor.ctl data=data/data.dat')
```

Comment: So would ORACLE_HOME point to the instant client location in this case?

Comment: @RussellQuinlan yes

Comment: With Instant Client, don't set ORACLE_HOME